# ERROR: Zend_Controller_Exception from Plesk cpanel after upgrading a server

Tags: cpanel, error, plesk, upgrade

After upgrading the server I used to get this type of error from Plesk cpanel

> Type: Zend_Controller_Exception
>   Message: Permission denied.#0
>   `/opt/psa/admin/plib/vendor/plesk/zendframework/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php(309)`: `Plesk\Application\Controller\Plugin\ForgeryProtection->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))` #1 `/opt/psa/admin/plib/vendor/plesk/zendframework/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(941)`: `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker->preDispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))` #2 `/opt/psa/admin/plib/Application/Web.php(39): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http))` #3 `/opt/psa/admin/htdocs/application.php(15): Plesk\Application_Web->run()` #4 `{main}`
>   File: Brokerer.php
>   Line: 312

[image]

What was the error related to Zend in the above context?